# Google Drive OAuth2 get token

Tags: php, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I just started learning Google tree up play and I have some questions.

1. How to log in with login link?

   ```
   session_start();
   require_once 'api/src/Google/Client.php';
   require_once 'api/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';


   $drive = new Google_Client();

   $drive->setClientId('XXXXXXXX-hc0ap9uujjvqpsci9ceitqsrro1d8415.apps.googleusercontent.com'); // Client ID

   $drive->setClientSecret('XXXXXXXXXXX'); //Client Secret

   $drive->setRedirectUri($url);

   $drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));


   $url = $drive->createAuthUrl();
   ```
2. How to get access_token?

Comment: Do you experience any exception when trying to log in? Pleas describe.

Comment: @Petr. You really need to read and understand OAuth before you start coding. There is no "login" in OAuth. There are at least three different approaches to obtaining an access token. Read and understand https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

You will get the URL to log in to Google from the `$drive->createAuthUrl()`. Google will return the credentials, including the access_token to the redirected URI.

I have set up a simple commented repo about using oAuth and Drive functions with the API in GitHub. You can find it here:

`https://github.com/numsu/google-drive-sdk-api-php-insert-file-parent-example`

Good luck learning! :)